# How to create indexes for query for better performance in sybase ase 15.4?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have 3 large tables: tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4. I have a sql query like:

```
select * from tab1 a, tab2 b, tab3 c, tab4 d
where 
    a.c1 = b.c1
and b.c2 = c.c2
and c.c3 = d.c3

and a.c4 = c.c4

and a.c3 = @var3
and a.c4 = @var4
and b.date >= @d1 and b.date <=@d2
and b.c5 =@var5
group by d.c6, a.c4, c.c7
order by d.c6, a.c4, c.c7
```

There are indexes created as: for each column in the where condition, there is a index created. For example, there are 3 columns in tab1 used in above query: c1, c3, c4. there are 3 indexes created: 
index on c1, index on c3, index onc4.

Same for all other tables.

Questions:
1. How to create a index for those columns appear in where condition? single colum index or combined index? For example, for tab1, one index include 3 columns c1, c3, c4 or 3 index for each single column?
2. If index also should be create for columns in group by?
3. If the order in where condition is important? For example, following 3 has any difference on performance?

```
where 
    a.c1 = b.c1
and b.c2 = c.c2
and c.c3 = d.c3

and a.c4 = c.c4  ----duplicate join???

and a.c3 = @var3
and a.c4 = @var4
and b.date >= @d1 and b.date <=@d2
and b.c5 =@var5
```

Or

```
where 
a.c3 = @var3
and a.c4 = @var4
and b.date >= @d1 and b.date <=@d2
and b.c5 =@var5

and a.c1 = b.c1
and b.c2 = c.c2
and c.c3 = d.c3
and a.c4 = c.c4  --duplicate join???
```

Or

```
where 
a.c3 = @var3
and a.c4 = @var4
and b.date >= @d1 and b.date <=@d2
and b.c5 =@var5

and a.c1 = b.c1
and b.c2 = c.c2
and c.c3 = d.c3
```

Answer (score 1):

How big is the table? What kind of locking scheme tables are following?

Generally, clustered indexes work better in case of ranged query but if tables are following DOL scheme then it's no good.

It's really hard to tell which indexes should be created without looking at the table but I would initially build them like

- Tab1: 2 different non-clustered index on C3 and C4
- Tab2: clustered index on date, non clustered index on C5
- Tab3: Unique clustered index in C2, C3 and C4

I also would break the query in smaller pieces:

- one for taking out all the rows (put them in #temp1)
- Create clustered index on C6, C4, C7 on #temp1
- write the final query with group by clause where only #temp1 will participate in group by clause. You can skip order by clause since we already have clustered on these columns